# AWS RDS Aurora MySQL Cluster, Reader Replica shows no connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I added a reader replica to my RDS Aurora MySQL cluster. The instance is running with minor cpu usage but it does not show connections on the monitoring page. I have enabled detailed monitoring. Access groups are the same as the writer instance.

How to I ensure that traffic is going to my reader instance?

Comment: When you create a read replica, then you will have 2 endpoints - writer and reader. Your application should aware of this thing, and you need to redirect traffic accordingly (i.e. `SELECT` goes to reader, and `INSERT` `UPDATE` `DELETE` goes to writer/master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS RDS Aurora  does not support splitting of read/write transactions,
In order to forward read only queries to read replica endpoint and read/write queries to your master endpoint you need to add function or a proxy to your application to inspect the query then forward it to read replica or to the master, in other word the application logic should manage this process.

Comment: I was dealing with WordPress and I was able to use a plugin, hypredb,  to split readonly traffic and read/write traffic. I also added auto-scaling to deal with future surges in connections. Thanks for the help